# Update_one in pymongo with different fields type

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

In mongoDB collection I have different field types. Is it possible update doc in this collection with update_one method?

```py
doc = {"upd_time": datetime.datetime.now(), "categories": [1,2,3]}
mng_collection.update_one({"_id": id}, {"$set": doc}, upsert=True)
```

That code replace existing array in categories field, but I need to add values from doc["categories"] array if not existing in collection doc array.

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Comment: In this document: "If the field is not an array, the operation will fail." First field in doc not array

Comment: push is for arrays. I get it that doc["categories"]  is an array, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `$push` with `$each` to add elements to the existing array. `$set` will always replace existing value with  new one.

You can try this:

```
doc = {"upd_time": datetime.datetime.now(), "categories": [1,2,3]}
mng_collection.update_one({"_id": id}, {
    "$set": { "doc.upd_time" : doc.upd_time},
    $push : {categories : {$each : doc.categories}}
}, upsert=True)
```

Read more about [$push documentation, and how to use it with $each here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/push/#push-modifiers).

Comment: Brilliant solution